# Different output generated by java.sql.Time from different server

Tags: java, time

I have tested the following code in four machines. Two of those are windows(win7 & win8), and two are linux(centos). Output on the windows pc are same(but different with linux).

```
java.sql.Time d = java.sql.Time.valueOf("19:54:17");
System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

Windows output: `50057000`
Linux output: `93257000`

Windows: `java version "1.6.0_26"`
Linux: `java version "1.6.0_24"`

Times are slightly different amongst the machines(in 2-3 minutes). But Windows are having `UTC+6` and Linux are having `GMT+6` timezone.

Another info. I have also had a run this code on [this online Java compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) and it shows the output `93257000`

I just want to have equal output from all my machines. What should I do?

**Update:** as you requested the output for this code `System.out.println(new Date(d.getTime()))`:

Windows: `Thu Jan 01 19:54:17 ALMT 1970`
Linux: `Thu Jan 01 19:54:17 GMT-06:00 1970`
Online Compiler: `Thu Jan 01 19:54:17 CST 1970`

Comment: Are you sure they are on the same timezone? What do you get if you print `new Date(d.getTime());`?

Comment: java.sql.Time is wrapper class to java.util.Date. Could not you use directly this class? If yes, than you could also use Calendar. And than your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the following one with mine one. This makes my long value same throughout the machines.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
```

More detail about this can be found at https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4487450

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bad conversion of timezone

```
50057000 = 13:54:17 = 19:56:17 - 6
93257000 = 25:54:17 = 19:56:17 + 6
```

Not really a solution, but the formatting wouldn't look so nice in comments.

I think you are losing the timezone information in the valueOf method. 
`d.getTime().toString()` will convert the time based on locale. Check if you have same timezone in java:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
java.sql.Time.valueOf("19:54:17").getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: But what should I do now? How can I use this with Time?

Comment: You will have to express your time in the same timezone but I have the feeling you are misusing the getTime() method. Could you please explain what your are trying to do? Why do you want to have the same value on all machines?

Comment: @Aligz I just need this to be worked same on all machines. Its a part of a `JPA` project(with `postgresql` db with a `time` field/column). Besides I am using four machines on my cluster.